# How does submit_tag know what info to submit in case of several inputs (text_field_tag, select_tag etc)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, textfield, search-form

I was recently working on a demo web app to try to learn more about ruby on rails and I was trying to implement a search page where users could search by two attributes at the same time - search courses by course name and by subject id. I had already dealt with the associations on the backend for the database and got a working search form after trial and error for a few hours.
However, I want to understand how and why it works, and also how specifically the submit_tag at the end knows what input to submit.

```
<div class = "row", id = "search_filter">
    <div class = "col-md-6">
        <%= form_tag("/courses", method: "get") do %>
            <%= label_tag :search_field, "Search by course name:" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search_field, params[:search_field] %>            
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-6">
        <%= label_tag :search_dropdown, "Search by subject:" %>
        <%= select_tag :search_dropdown, options_from_collection_for_select(Subject.all, "id", "name", params[:search_field]) %>   
    </div>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: "btn btn-md btn-primary", name: nil %>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

The layout looks a bit odd because I wanted the text_field and dropdown menu to be side by side and the search button below them. Is this a good implementation for a form or is there a better way to go about it (i.e. using a form_for). A lot of it was built by taking bits of advice from different places online, so I don't know if everything I've included is necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Your ERB seems invalid. You're currently producing `<div class="col-md-6"><form></div></form>` (simplified it a bit). Since you close the div inside the form you should also open it in the form. Alternatively you can move the div closing tag outside of the form.

Comment: So that seemed like a logical thing to me too. Having a form start in one div and end in another shouldn't work. However, it does. I checked and verified and the search form works with both inputs. Which is why I was trying to understand why

Comment: The resulting HTML should be valid though. The reason it might work is because HTML is not strict XML anymore. Therefore the browser might interpret the closing tag. When pulling your current code through [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org) it results in the [following errors](https://i.imgur.com/KED099l.png), where the result should be something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Bqu9OVw.png).

Answer (score 0):

All of the `<input>` tags inside your `<form>` will be submitted when you submit the form. The only thing that Rails is doing behind the scenes is generating the HTML for your form, so a quick read through this might clarify a few things about HTML forms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms

Your form is perfectly valid. You might consider adding some logic to your controller that searches by the parameters supplied.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, Rails interprets it as a Hash of key-values called `params`. In your case, it will submit (with its correspondant values):

```
params: {
"search_field" => "",
"search_dropdown" => ""
}
```

then, in the controller, it's up to you what to do with the params they give. perhaps return a list of objects with the `search_field` or to create or update an object in the DB. The submit_tag button does the same as a form submit; keep in mind that those form helpers are just methods to output HTML in a simpler way for Rails to understand.

more info related on forms [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/form_helpers.html).